# How are different versions of netstandard and netcoreapp compatible?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm struggling to find any official blog post or documentation which could answer me the following questions:

1. If I have a netstandard2.0 library, can I have a dependency on a library which has only targeted netstandard1.x?

   - Is the change in the major version between netstandard1.x and netstandard2.0 a sign of incompatibility or something else?
2. If I have a library targeting netstandard2.0 which has a dependency on an ASP.NET Core 2.0.x package (e.g. Http.Abstractions) can I use this library from a netcoreapp2.1 application then?

   - How will the dependency on Http.Abstractions be resolved? Will it downgrade for the entire netcoreapp2.1 app?
   - Even if this theoretically works, is this a supported case by Microsoft?
3. Should/can a netstandard2.0 library have a dependency on a ASP.NET Core 2.1.x NuGet package?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET Standard is the contract. Which is implemented by .NET Core, Mono. .NET Framework etc.

So take for example .NET Core 1.0, [as per the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), supports any .NET Standard 1.x while .NET Core 2.0, supports .NET Standard 2.0

> If I have a netstandard2.0 library, can I have a dependency on a library which has only targeted netstandard1.x?

**Yes**. A higher version of .NET Standard can depend on a lower version. Same as a higher version of net4x or netcoreapp can depend on a lower. They are super sets of the API.

> If I have a library targeting netstandard2.0 which has a dependency on an ASP.NET Core 2.0.x package (e.g. Http.Abstractions) can I use this library from a netcoreapp2.1 application then?

**Yes**. That is because the Http.Abstractions is also targeting .NET Standard and not .NET Core (netcoreapp). That is also why ASP.NET Core can be used with the full framework (a source of confusion often).

> Should/can a netstandard2.0 library have a dependency on a ASP.NET Core 2.1.x NuGet package?

**No**. .NET Standard doesn't support .NET Core. So a library which targets only .NET Standard cannot depend on .NET Core

Comment: Thanks, you have actually answered all my questions with the explanations which you gave. Funny thing is, I knew all of that 6 months ago and after a little break trying to refresh my memory again totally confused me. The best resources to really understand this are independent blog posts, SO answers like this and listening to standups, which is all good, but a massive fail on Microsoft to document this somewhere prominently, so .NET devs and especially new people to .NET can get their head around. I doubt someone new to .NET will understand any of this, which is a shame.

Comment: _A higher version of .NET Standard can depend on a lower version_ **CAN** is the right word here. This doesn't necessarly mean that its API compatible though. For example if you have Dependency Injection Extensions for netstandard 1.0 its unlikely to work when referenzed from netstandard 2.0 since  there were breaking changes in the API of classes within the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace

Comment: Surely the packages can be incompatible. Targeting framework monikors don't affect that at all. They will ensure that the API available is consistent. Even with . NET Standard 2.0 when running on .NET Framework 4.6.2 you might get some runtime error since there are some APIs not really available.

Comment: If I want to test a .NET Standard 2.0 library and only have .NET Core 2.1 environment (Linux), I need to choose a .NET Core 2.1 test project. But that combination fails to compile, giving me a number of errors like this one:

4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

Comment: (Continue)

Generally version 2.1.1.0 of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions is used, but from somewhere 2.0.0.0 popped up and provoked the error.
So something is not compatible here.